# CSS animation not applying on ::before and ::after

Tags: css, css-animations

I have this heart animation from internet, `div` uses `::before` and `::after` to make a heart shape.

I have modified it so I can change the color from red to pink. The issue is that I can't change the color of `::before` and `::after` using the `thump` animation. I have added another animation to change color of `::before` and `::after`. While the thump can scale `::before` and `::after` but not change the color.

`thum` is supposed to change the color of `::before` and `::after`?

```css
.heart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  animation-name: thump;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.heart::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  animation-name: change-color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.heart::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  animation-name: change-color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes thump {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: pink;
  }
}

@keyframes change-color {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Comment: It actually does changes the background I think you are not able to see it clearly. Change the background from green to something else and then you will see the change.

Comment: yes it is changing the background, but it dosn;t changes when you remove `change-color` this animation

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. It is better to keep them change color and thump separated. If you want you can try to add thump animation to ```::before``` and ```::after ``` but that will scale them too. It is better to keep ```thump``` and ```change-color``` for different purposes.

Comment: `thump` is changing color for div but not for  `::before` and `::after`, I am curios that  `::before` and `::after` scaled by `thump` but not changing color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was to get rid off of the redundant background colors props from the div and the selectors; swap the colors in thump & change-color. If that solves your question.

#### Why thump not changing bg color for before and after?

Because it does not interfere with those two as we are only using change-color animation for those selectors.

```css
.heart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  animation: thump 2s infinite;
}

.heart::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  animation: change-color 2s infinite;
}

.heart::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  animation: change-color 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes thump {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color:pink ;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: red;
  }
}
@keyframes change-color{
  0% {
    background-color:pink ;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Comment: I think thump is scaling before and after, but not changing the bg color, why?

Comment: @IhtishamKhan because before and after are selectors for the heart class, although it seems same objective item, but those two are different entities to be styled on. As you can see thump works with the main heart class where as changecolor works with both before and after. If you wanted thump to be able to work on everything then the transform scale used in thump will make the before and after elements as much bigger and it will break the shape of the heart.

Comment: So it means my technique was right, except the redundant CSS. I was just confirming

Answer (score 0):

```css
.heart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  animation-name: change-color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.heart::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  animation-name: before-after;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.heart::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  animation-name: before-after;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}



@keyframes change-color {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: pink;
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes before-after {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```